# Distributive law when querying dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple data frame [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOlk.png) where I would like to query the data frame using a boolean distributive law in the following way:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOlk.png) Dataframe example

```
    users   x  y    w    z
1     tom  30  12   65  100
3    john  30  13   76  200
3  rachel  30  25   43  200
4  rachel   5  10   87  300
5  rachel  10  45   65  300
6    jeff  20  50   92  400
7    jeff  30  43   54  400
8    jeff  50  20   46  200
```

Obtain all rows that satisfies one of the following conditions:
`(x == 30 & z == 200) | (y == 20 & z == 200) | (w > 60 & z == 200)`

I thought in applying the distributive law, but it did not work:

`df.query(z == 200 & (x == 30 | y == 20 | w > 60))`

[image]

How can I apply this condition when querying the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working perfectly with `""`, but your error seems this is no problem here:

```
df = df.query("z == 200 & (x == 30 | y == 20 | w > 60)")
print (df)
    users   x   y   w    z
3    john  30  13  76  200
3  rachel  30  25  43  200
8    jeff  50  20  46  200
```

Comment: Mistyping on my side.

Comment: @xeon123 - so `x,y,z` was some variables?